# SQL Server 2005 Instance memory allocation and SSIS DTSExec performance

Tags: .net, database, sql-server-2005, ssis

We have multi GB files coming every day to be loaded to SQL Server 2005 instance via SSIS packages. To load those large data files to SQL Server asynchronously, we built multi threaded .NET application. This application uses DTSExec command line executable to invoke SSIS packages. It also instantiate 5 queues and 5 streams for each queue. So, total of 25 files can be loaded at the same time.

This application, say "AsyncLoader", lives in the same machine as SQL Server 2005 instance and SSIS Instance. The server machine is huge. 32 CPU, 128 GB memory, SAN etc. We allocated 5% of the memory to the OS and the rest of the memory is reserved for SQL Server 2005 instance. Here's my options;

1) Move SSIS instance and AsyncLoader to its own machine so that DTSExec has its own large memory space to work in. Eliminate SSIS CPU cycles from SQL Server machine.

2) Keep all the players (SQL Server, SSIS, AsyncLoader) in the same machine and reduce total allocated memory on SQL Server to 75% so that DTSExec has more memory to operate.

At this time, we don't have too much time to do proof of concept work or benchmarking for each solution. I just wanted to get you folks' idea to see if someone else had that setup and what would be the best practices. Also, moving packages from one machine to another is a huge burden, so even though option 1 seems so obvious, we need hard facts to see if it brings considerable performance gains.

Comment: One more thing; 

Last week AsyncLoader went into an infinite loop and crashed the database server. That gives another up vote for moving the services and SSIS to its own machine. If the application crashes the server machine, database server will still be up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for 2 boxes, plain and simple.

I'd also hope you're on 64 bit too with 128 GB RAM.

That said, the SSIS install is a separate executable from sqlservr.exe instance. So you may be starving SSIS of CPU not memory.. You could try changing [processor affinity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187104.aspx) to allow SQL Server to use only 16 cores and let the memory find it's own level. I've not played with the other IO affinity option, so have no comments.

However, you're AsyncLoader thingy may merit a box of it's own: a 3 server solution...

Other points: do you have antivirus installed? Is the SAN a bottleneck?

Comment: Yes gbn, box is 64bit OS. 
SAN is not a bottleneck.